# No matching version found for @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.1

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, npm-install, nexus

**No matching version found for @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.1**

This issue we have seen when we use my company npm repository(nexus).
This is working as expected when i have removed registry information in the **.npmrc**

Below is the error log:

> ```
> npm ERR! code ETARGET
> npm ERR! notarget No matching version for @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.1.
> npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your depenedencies are requesting
> npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist,
> npm ERR! notarget 
> npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'newbusinessapp'
> npm ERR! notarget
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\TITEMB\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-22T09_45_41_774Z-debug.log
> ```

Hope i get right solution here.

Comment: This version is not present in my org npm registry as per npm still it should fetch from npm repo in case of not present. isn't it ?

Comment: It depends on your nexus configuration. It must contain a configuration to make it work  as a proxy towards some online npm repo (ie https://registry.npmjs.org).

Comment: Seeing your .npmrc would probably help troubleshoot if empty it works.